# How to calculate Total hours using query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have field named "Time" in my table. I want to calculate total hours.

```
Time
3:00:00
4:00:00
5:00:00
```

Output should be 2hr.
How can I achieve this? Please help me to solve it.

I tried below query but it did not work as expected.

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timeSpent` ) ) ) AS timeSum  
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: `total hours` should be 3+4+5=12, do you want to `difference` between the highest number and the lowest? being 5-3=2

Answer (score 2):

If you need the maximum time span between values, then try with:

```
SELECT MAX(timeSpent) - MIN(timeSpent) FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table have an id as a primary key auto incremental, so you query will be:

```
SELECT FLOOR(sum( abs( SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(t1.`timeSpent`))  -  SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.`timeSpent`)) )/10000)) as total 
FROM YourTableName t1
inner join YourTableName t2 
on t1.id = t2.id + 1;
```

Comment: i have values "03:16:00" and "03:18:00" .Query gives output "0".output should be 0.03 hours

Comment: @piyush of course it will give you "0" the difference between 2 time with minutes and you want the difference with hours so I use **FLOOR** function to round to hours only. if you want any difference you can remove **FLOOR** function and in this case output will be 0.0200 = 0.02.

Comment: I want to calculate user wise and i have UserId. how can i achieve this.